# Use built jar instead of module in project

Tags: java, maven

The idea is:

In project we have module X and Y. Module X using code from module Y and have dependency on it in pom. Module Y built with `mvn install`. But they are located in the same project so module when module X using methods/classes from module Y it uses code that located in project and not from jar.

I want to use jar in X after `mvn install` of module Y. It will be useful for me because when the code in Y will be changed it will influence on module X only if I build new version of it. How can I do this?

Hope my idea is understandable. Thanks for answers.

Comment: Can you show the structure of the project and directories because I'm not sure if I understand your setup correctly... best would be a full example project on github or alike...

Comment: Okey, if I don't forget about it I will try to replecate example today

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Answer (score 1):

What you have encountered is not a bug but a feature because in most cases that is the behavior desired.

The simplest way is to separate X and Y completely so you cannot see the sources for Y when working on X. If using an IDE you can also tell it to ignore Y completely, and then undo that when needed.